# Palette Manager on Windows 10

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm reading through Charles Petzold's *Programming Windows (5th ed.)* and was wondering if there is any way to see the effects of `CreatePalette`, `RealizePalette` and `UpdateColors` functions. I tried switching the *Reduced color mode* setting in the .exe properties on but it didn't seem to do anything. Should I spin up a Windows 2000 VM or is there a way to switch to 256 color mode in Windows 10

Comment: Not sure how compatible the DWM is, 95-XP is probably better.

Comment: Forget about that. It's too old.

Comment: Why are you wasting time learning about something that has been obsolete for 20+ years? 256 color mode hasn't been supported in Windows since XP, and isn't supported in most modern video cards.

Comment: Vista technically can use XP drivers but yeah, palette is old tech. Windows 8+ requires DWM.

Comment: You should be rejoicing in not ever needing to work with palettes

Comment: @KenWhite I know, I know. I just wanted to try something on my old PC without having to debug on an old PC